# Handling app download window in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I am trying to automate instagram by using selenium and python.
I went till login without any problem.
But after logging in, instagram pops up a window saying "experience the best version of instagram by getting the app" which is a download link of instagram app. 
I want to ignore this download pop up window, and having trouble with it
1)no buttons to click, only close(❌) button.
2)xpath of close(❌) button not working
Please help me
And thank you

Answer (score 2):

Since you are saying xpath of close(❌) button not working , you can go try to pass the `Escape` key to close the pop up window.

In Java

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).build().perform();

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```

In Python

```
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()

robot = Robot() 
robot.press_and_release(Keys.escape)
```

Comment: @Nihal shetty , did it help you?